# Accidentally linking c_str() strings

Tags: c++, string, c-str

I'm trying to assign a string to a struct value, which works, but the value somehow links to the variable:

```
string tmp;
struct test_struct{
    const char *server, *user; 
};
test_struct test;

tmp = "foo";
test.server = tmp.c_str();
cout << test.server << endl;

tmp = "bar";
test.user = tmp.c_str();
cout << test.user << endl;

cout << "" << endl;

cout << test.server << endl;
cout << test.user << endl;
```

The output is:

```
foo
bar

bar
bar
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Ask yourself -- where in memory do those pointers point?  How long are those pointers valid?  Using raw pointers means tracking ownership and tracking lifetime of data that is pointed to.  A simpler approach would be to use `std::string` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Note that accessing `test.server` after execuing `tmp = "bar";` leads to undefined behavior. The pointer returned by [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) becomes invalidated as soon as you invoke a non-const member function of the string (with a few exceptions). That includes [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

Comment: `server` and `user` store the address of whatever sequence of characters are in `tmp`. If you change the contents of `tmp`, two things could happen: 1) the new value is written at the same memory location, or 2) the new value is written at a new memory location. If, after `tmp` is changed, you read from `server` or `user`, which still point to the original address, two things could happen: A) you read the new value, or B) you can read basically whatever. But since 1 and 2 are implementation details over which you have no control, you should only consider your code yields B behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct test_struct{
    const char *server, *user; 
};
test_struct test;
```

Okay, so `test.server` is a pointer.

```
test.server = tmp.c_str(); // 1
cout << test.server << endl; // 2

tmp = "bar"; // 3
test.user = tmp.c_str();
cout << test.user << endl;

cout << "" << endl;

cout << test.server << endl; // 4
```

In 1, you set `test.server` to point to the contents of `tmp`. In 2, you output what `test.server` points to, which is fine.

In 3, you modify the contents of `tmp`. So now, `test.server` points to something that no longer exists -- the former contents of `tmp`.

In 4, you output what `test.server` points to. But that was the contents of `tmp` back at 1, which you destroyed in 3.

You cannot output something that you obliterated.

Comment: Well, apparently you can, but you don't get the results you hoped for